# Error in PSTricks

Tags: pdftex, pstricks

Why does this code produce an error and how to fix it?

By the way, I use Texmaker in MikTeX.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{pst-func}
\begin{document}
\psset{xunit=1.0cm,yunit=1.0cm,algebraic=true,dimen=middle,dotstyle=o,dotsize=5pt 0,linewidth=0.8pt,arrowsize=3pt 2,arrowinset=0.25}
\begin{pspicture*}(-2.,-1.5)(2.,2.5)
\psaxes[labelFontSize=\scriptstyle,xAxis=true,yAxis=true,Dx=0.5,Dy=0.5,ticksize=-2pt 0,subticks=2]{<->}(0,0)(-2.,-1.5)(2.,2.5)
\psplotImp[linewidth=0.4pt](-3.0,-3.0)(3.0,3.0){0.01388742374854553+1.9858243449267068*y^2+3.0*y^3-2.0*y^4-0.0034236125287306907*x^1-0.336756945862064*x^1*y^2-2.0*x^2-2.0*x^2*y^2}
\end{pspicture*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have no error message. Is this the exact code which produces your error message?

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: @Torbjørn This is the error:

! Undefined control sequence.
\XC@usec@lor ...string \color@ #1#2\endcsname \@@
\fi \space
l.9 \psplot
[linewidth=0.4pt](-3.0,-3.0)(3.0,3.0){0.01388742374854553+1.9858...
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., '\hobx'), type 'I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., 'I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Comment: @Bernard Any idea about the error (see above)? **Teokan**: Looks like that has something to do with `xcolor` (a color package, loaded by `pstricks`), but I don't know why you would get the error. Can you compile `\listfiles\documentclass{article} \usepackage{pstricks-add} \pagestyle{empty} \usepackage{pst-func} \begin{document}  abc \end{document}`, and then add the `.log` file that is produced to your question? (Click the *edit* link right above these comments to edit your post.)

Comment: did you use pdflatex instead of latex?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, I did use pdflatex.

Comment: pstricks needs latex/dvips (usually)

Comment: Here is the link to the log file: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jklpmn0879fgw4q/test.log?dl=0)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle What does that mean?

Comment: instead of `pdflatex` run the document with `xelatex`!

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

The error message you show in comments is not the first one. the first error reported is

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \c@lor@to@ps
```

Unfortunately pstricks still doesn't catch that and give a more helpful error message but the reason is that pdflatex has been used. pstricks needs a PostScript interpreter and so you have to use latex and dvips rather than pdflatex. There are packages to allow limited use with pdflatex, but mostly that works by running (just) the pspicture as a separate document with latex and then including the generated pdf into the main pdflatex processed document.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: @TeokanDuranDemircan instead of typing `pdflatex file.tex` you need `latex file.tex` followed by `dvpd file.dvi` to get postscript then finally `ps2pdf file.ps` to make PDF That is the sequence of commands, your editor probably has that in a menu somewhere but I do not know texmaker.

Answer (score 2):

With TeXMaker, you can go to the `Options -> Configure TeXmaker` menu, then

- either add `\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}`  to your preamble (*after* `pstricks` related packages), and `--enable-write18` to the parameters for `pdflatex`, as in this image:

[image]

- or change the default for `Quick build` to `Latex+dvips+ps2pdf+View Pdf` or `XeLaTeX+ViewPDF`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks like an exported  one from another GUI. Without such a GUI it is much more easier to create what you need:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pst-func}
\begin{document}
\psset{algebraic,unit=2}
\begin{pspicture*}(-2.,-1.5)(2.,2.5)
\psaxes[labelFontSize=\scriptstyle,Dx=0.5,
  Dy=0.5,ticksize=-2pt 0,subticks=2]{<->}(0,0)(-2.,-1.5)(2.,2.5)
\psplotImp[linewidth=1pt,stepFactor=0.2,linecolor=red](-3.0,-3.0)(3.0,3.0)%
   {0.0138+1.9858*y^2+3.0*y^3-2.0*y^4-0.0034236*x-0.3367*x*y^2-2.0*x^2-2.0*x^2*y^2}
\end{pspicture*}
\end{document}
```

Run it with `xelatex` or `latex->dvips->ps2pdf` or with loading package `auto-pst-pdf` and then also with `pdflatex

[image]